# How to send Lambda logs to StackDriver instead of CloudWatch?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, stackdriver

I am considering sending my logs into StackDriver instead of CloudWatch. But from the docs, it seem to only describe how to do it with EC2. What about lambda? I prefer to send logs directly to StackDriver instead of StackDriver reading from CloudWatch to remove the CloudWatch costs entirely.

Comment: See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/856724/exporting-cloudwatch-logs-to-stackdriver

Comment: @Kolban yes I saw that, but like I mentioned, I wanted to look for a way to send logs directly if possible

Comment: old, but oh well. The reason it's _not_ a great idea to send them from the lambda code, is that you are paying for ms there. An extra request in the lambda lifecycle can easily double your costs.

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver supports the metric types from Amazon Lambda listed in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_aws#aws-lambda)

To use these metrics in charting or alerting, your Google Cloud Platform project or AWS account must be associated with a Workspace.

After you have a Workspace, you can add more GCP projects and AWS accounts to it using the [Adding monitored projects](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces/guide#monitor-multiple-projects) instructions.

If you plan to monitor more than just your host project, then the best practice is to use a new, empty GCP project to host the Workspace and then to add the projects and AWS accounts you want to monitor to your Workspace. This lets you choose a useful name for your host project and Workspace, and gives you a little more flexibility in moving monitored projects between Workspaces. The following diagram shows Workspace W monitoring GCP projects A and B and AWS account D:

[image]

Monitoring creates this AWS connector project when you add an AWS account to a Workspace. The connector project has a name beginning with AWS Link, and it has the same parent organization as the Workspace. To get the name and details about your AWS connector projects, go to the [Inspecting Workspace](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/workspaces/#inspect-ws) section.

In the GCP Console, AWS connector projects appear as regular GCP projects. Don't use connector projects for any other purpose, and don't delete them while your Workspace is still connected to your AWS account.

Comment: This sounds amazing. Does it automatically also import logs? Or do I need to do something else for that?

Comment: Similar question, after doing the above, I don't see my Lambda logs showing up in the "AWS Link" project the connect created.